# Correcting sql query to exclude sessions under 2 min

Tags: sql, datetime

Im am trying to write a code that will remove any entires that are within 2 mins of each other on the same day for each user_id.

for example here is the table:

| user_id | day | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 00:55:54 |
| x | 1 | 00:55:55 |
| x | 1 | 00:56:01 |
| x | 2 | 16:11:43 |
| x | 2 | 16:12:01 |
| x | 2 | 16:15:02 |
| x | 2 | 16:30:07 |
| x | 2 | 16:31:08 |
| x | 2 | 16:40:09 |
| x | 2 | 16:41:02 |

So if within the same day there was some times that didn't last more than 2 mins i would like to exclude does 2 entires.

Note: day and time were gotten by using the day() and time() on a datetime column called timestamp

The code i have is:

```
  WITH frames AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id, day(timestamp), time(timestamp) AS starttime, COALESCE(
        LEAD(time(timestamp)) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, day(timestamp)), 
        '23:59:59'
        ) AS final
  FROM events
)
SELECT user_id, day(timestamp), starttime, final, TIMEDIFF(final, starttime) AS duration 
FROM frames
WHERE TIMEDIFF(final, starttime) < 120;
```

but i get this error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'timestamp' in 'field list'`

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  What if you have 10 entries spaced 90 seconds apart?  What do you then want?  And tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want rows that are more than 2 minutes from the previous row:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by date(timestamp) order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from events e
     ) e
where prev_timestamp is null or
      prev_timestamp < timestamp - interval '2 minute';
```

You do not specify the database you are using, so this uses reasonable database syntax that might need to be modified for your database.

Also note that in databases that support the function, `day()` typically returns the day of the month.  You want a function that removes the time component, which is usually `date()` or `cast( as date)`.

Comment: i can't get of the error sign on the `select e.*` i think it may have something to do with the `where` statement because it is fine until i type that specifically the interval clause

Comment: @doskitele . . . Without knowing what database you are using, it is rather hard to make syntax suggestions, but both `e.*`s are fine.